# How to run a python script in browser?

Tags: python

I want to display html from a python script in a browser. How do I run this script so I can view this in a browser.
Code so far:

**`index.py`**

```
### to run python in browser i have added below lines
#!/usr/bin/env python
header = open("header.html", "r")
print header
```

and my **`header.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A Python To Do list</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: basically you cannot. Use some frameworks such us django, bottle, etc

Comment: my main focus in how to run script in brower and thanks for your time @nu11p01n73R

Comment: You don't run Python neither PHP _in your browser_.

Comment: @bereal i mean to say show output in browser

Comment: @Riturajratan you'd use a framework - you don't normally (although you can but it'd be foolish to do so) use Python like it's PHP... look at flask/bottle for instance

Comment: You would agree, that's a different thing. Consider using [`SimpleHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) for something very simple and any of the aforementioned frameworks (or a dozen of others) for anything serious.

Answer (score 2):

Bassically you can use BaseHTTPServer like this and run your code.

localhost.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import BaseHTTPServer

class HTTPFrontend(object) :
    def __init__(self, port) :
        self.server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', port), self.RequestHandler)
        print "Web interface listening on http://localhost:" + str(port)

    def start(self) :
        self.server.serve_forever()

    def stop(self) :
        self.server.socket.close()

    class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler) :
        def do_GET(self) :
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()

            templateFile = open("home.html")
            template = templateFile.read()
            templateFile.close()

            message = "this is how simple templating works"

            self.wfile.write(template % {'message': message})

        def do_POST(self) :
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write("this is a POST")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = HTTPFrontend(8080)
    server.start()
```

home.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Python | Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            %(message)s
    </body>
</html>
```

And if you open `http://localhost:8654` in your browser you get:

```
this is how simple templating works
```

Comment: this file put on which folder

Comment: anywhere you want to run it for as long as the html file is sibling file of py file as you notice in the localhost.py